# How to host server from laptop?

Tags: python, http, port, portforwarding, httpserver

I am trying to make my laptop a http server. For starters, I am running:

"python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080"

I think I should be able to access this server at http://my.pub.lic.ip:8080 (I obtained my.pub.lic.ip from www.whatismyipaddress.com). However, this does not work. I do not know what the problem is. Could it be that:

1. Network service provider does not allow hosting?
2. Disabling firewall? (I did try "sudo ufw disable" (I run ubuntu) but it did not fix the issue).
3. Port 8080 in the URL does not map to 8080 on my machine? (should I do some port forwarding or something? If so, how should I do it?)

Comment: It could definitely be port forwarding. Have a look into your router documentation (or on the net) if you need help with the configuration.

Comment: Are you trying to make your application visible to people all over the internet?

Comment: Where are you accessing it from?  Could one of your routers be providing a NAT?  They behave in many ways like a firewall

Comment: @LaurentJalbertSimard : Thanks! Apart from me using google, it will be great if you could point me to some documentation that you have looked at before.

Comment: @user814064: Yes, that is what I am trying to do.

Comment: It does really depend on you router model, find it and I'll point you to the right video tutorial.

Comment: @CortAmmon : I am trying to access it from a remote machine (outside my subnet). I am unsure of the NAT though. Considering that is the case, how can I fix it?

Comment: Check the IP address of your local machine (such as with ifconfig).  If the address it gives is your public IP, then there is no NAT.  If it is different (usualy 196.168.*.* or 10.*.*.*), then you have to look up how your particular router can be configure to forward to you

Comment: @CortAmmon: It is different. I guess what you and Laurent said point me towards looking at the router config. I will go ahead with that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is your router model number and brand? While you are at it, go to the terminal and type "ifconfig" with out the quotes and tell us what local ip it shows for ipv4 address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate all inputs. I recently found out what you all meant by "open" the port. The answer lies in iptables (specifics of which:  https://superuser.com/questions/634469/need-iptables-rule-to-accept-all-incoming-traffic )

Also for external clients to access the server, one has to change the /etc/hosts file to establish the server name -> IP mapping.

This article was really helpful to me as someone who does not know basics of networking (http://computernetworkingnotes.com/network-administration/how-to-configure-apache-server-in-linux.html) . It gives a step by step process of setting up an apache server.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

1st is you must set a static local ip for your computer that is running the server.

If you want to access it from a local network, all you really need to do is open the port 8080 in your firewall, then go on another computer on the network and type the local ip of the server and there you go..

example for local network: 192.168.1.150:8080

But if you want to run it for the public, you have to go into your router and enable port forwarding to port 8080 and open port 8080 in your firewall.

example for public access where x.x.x.x is the public ip: x.x.x.x:8080

If there is anything else please let me know. :)

Answer (score 1):

connect to 127.0.0.1 instead of your public ip.

127.0.0.1 is called localhost, and always points to your own machine.

That way it doesn't matter if any NAT routing firewalls or anonymous proxy servers are hiding your local network IP from whatismyipaddress.com

Comment: Are you asking me to use http://127.0.0.1:8080 ? If so, it will work for me but will not allow remote machines to access my server, right?

Comment: Yes, that will tell you at least that the server is succesfully running on your laptop.  If you want someone on the internet to access it also, then assuming you have a standard home setup with a home router/modem, then you'll need to setup portforwarding on the router to forward port 8080.  Only the router really has the public ip address, so when someone connects to 8080 they are connecting to the router.  You need to tell the router to forward that connection on to your laptop